# Multimedia : Path to sound and video files

Tags: paths, multimedia

I have the same sound on transition between frames in a quizz beamer pdf. Each quizz file will use the same sound file, all quizz are not in the same directory. I want to avoid copying the same sound file in each quizz directory.

Could one use an absolute path to the sound file, or make it reachable by another way?

I try to put in my personnal `\texmf` but it doesn't work.